# What is difference between Worker thread vs Background thread android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Can any one explain Where we are using worker thread and Background thread with some real-time examples briefly.

Comment: Please read the official documentation of Google Android developer [Procresses and Threads] (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: in Android "background" and "worker" threads are the same.

Answer (score 2):

They are synonyms. You can check the android [Worker threads reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) where they remark that:

> Because of the single threaded model described above, it's vital to
>   the responsiveness of your application's UI that you do not block the
>   UI thread. If you have operations to perform that are not
>   instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate threads
>   (**"background" or "worker" threads**).

Comment: thank you sir, but can you tell me some real time example..When we have to use worker thread and when we have to use background thread

Answer (score 0):

Background thread as name states runs separate from main thread and does not hang the main thread so its a async operation and a Worker thread is runs parallel to main thread. In short we can run worker thread and background thread at the same time together.

Background threads are dead once the application exists whereas worker threads complete the action even if the application closed.

Comment: thank you sir but can you tell me some real time example..When we have to use worker thread and when we have to use background thread.